# How to use Rx to asynchronously query Twitter search?

Tags: c#, frameworks, system.reactive

I'm thinking about using Rx (Reactive Framework) in order to asynchronously query Twitter search API on a given keyword. The sample app I'd like to build should be able to display new tweets in the console.

Do you think it is possible to do that ? Would it be simpler than using standard programming techniques ?

How would you do that ?

Thank !
Jeremy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick mockup of how it could be done. Note, I've only done a simple web request but this should easily extend to interact with the Twitter API.

**Update:** my previous sample didn't work well with repeating requests. The following improved sample uses `Observable.Interval` to generate a continuous stream of ticks, driving the creation of requests and response download.

```
Observable
    .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))
    .Select(ticks => (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://demicode.com"))
    .Select(request => Observable.FromAsyncPattern(request.BeginGetResponse, 
        asyncResult => 
        {
            using(var response = request.EndGetResponse(asyncResult))
            using (var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                return DateTime.Now.ToString() + sr.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }))
    .SelectMany(getContent => getContent())
    .ObserveOnDispatcher()
    .Subscribe(content => downloadContent.Text = content);
```

**Update 2:** Seems like using libraries like [TweetSharp](http://tweetsharp.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=AsyncRequests&referringTitle=Documentation) would handle the Twitter requests nicely for you. `Observable.FromAsyncPattern` combined with the async `twitter.BeginRequest` method makes a nice combination.

Comment: Thank you for the sample. Do you think it is possible to fetch each 5 seconds the new tweets ? As your example does not use Twitter, how would you do to check if the content of the page has changed in the last 5 seconds and show thoses changes ?

Comment: @Jalfp: see my improved sample. Still no Twitter integration though (I'll look into that if time permits), but the content download is at least downloading each 5 seconds.

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort ! I'll try to use your sample for my idea. I really appreciate your help :-)

Comment: @Jalfp: how's the app going? added a tip to my answer if you haven't already found it.